# IConfiguration is always NULL .NET CORE in Blazor app / Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, configuration, blazor

IConfiguration is always null no matter what i try.. I have also tried to add singleton to the startup class, but always null...

Startup class

```
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

Here is my Security class

```
        IConfiguration _configuration { get;} **<<always null**
        public Security(IConfiguration configuration) **<<always null**
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
         public  string GetConnectionString()
        {
            string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("localDb");
            return connectionString;

        }
```

Here is my Index.Razor page

```
 namespace WebbiSkoolsQuizManager.Pages
{
    public class IndexBase : ComponentBase
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public async Task TryLogin(string user, string pass)
        {
            
        }
       
         

        public async Task AddUserHash(string username, string password)
        {
            Security secure = new Security(Configuration);
            string connectionstring = secure.GetConnectionString();
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionKeys": {
    "localDb": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Quiz;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Thank you in advance, i have searched high and low, regarding a fix for blazor specific but i cant find anything.. (P.S its .Net core 3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this: `public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }`

Should be:

```
[Inject]
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

Note: You can't simply define a property of a service, and expect it to be populated... If you're using a Razor component class definition (.cs) as in your case, you can inject the service by using the `[Inject]` attribute. If you're using a Razor component (.razor), you can either use the `@inject` directive at the view portion of the component, as for instance:

```
@page "/"
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
```

or in the `@code` section, like this:

```
@code
{
    [Inject]
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

}
```

Note also that if you want to inject a service into a normal C# class, you'll need to use constructor injection

Answer (score 0):

I started a new blazor project (.Net 6) and when I @inject the IConfiguration to my .razor file, the configuration object turns out to be always null.